# How to create submodule with Angular

Tags: angular

I am creating an app in angular 2 with CLI , my app module is going too long so now i want to create submodules

**My submodule is**

```js
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { ProjectComponent } from './project.component';
    import { ProjectListingComponent } from './project-listing/project-listing.component';
    import { ProjectCreateUpdateComponent } from './project-create-update/project-create-update.component';
    
    
    // routing set for project module 
    
    const routes: Routes = [
        {path:'project/add' , component:ProjectCreateUpdateComponent},
        {path:'project/:id/edit' , component:ProjectCreateUpdateComponent},
        {path:'project-listing' ,component:ProjectListingComponent},
    ];
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule],
      providers: []
    })
    export class ProjectRoutingModule { }
    
    
    // Main module for project 
    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ProjectRoutingModule
      ],
      declarations: [ProjectComponent, ProjectListingComponent, ProjectCreateUpdateComponent ]
    })
    export class ProjectModule { }
```

**> Main module is**

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
    //import { ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import { routing } from './app.routing';
    import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

    import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';

    //custom modules 
    import {ProjectModule} from './project_module/project.module';   

    import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';  
    ...
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        GradeComponent,
        GradeListingComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        GradeComponent,
        ...

      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        routing,       
        MaterialModule.forRoot(),
        ReactiveFormsModule,        
        ProjectModule   
    
      ],
      providers: [
        NotificationsService,
        DatePipe,
        GradeService,
        ...        
        ],
        exports: [
            ConfirmDialogComponent,
        ],
      entryComponents: [
        logsShow
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

> But issue is coming my submodule can not access material module value
> and other module/plugins i have use in app.module ..
>
> What is the way to get this .. facing also issue on routing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is perfectly normal. If you want to access `MaterialModule` from a sub-module, you'll have to declare `MaterialModule` in this sub-module.

This'll be pretty lame with all your shared modules ...

The basic way to solve this is just to create a `SharedModule`, import/export everything that you want to use in your whole app.

For example, here's the shared.module.ts file of my current project :

```
export const modules = [
  CommonModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  HttpModule,
  RouterModule,
  MaterialModule,
  FlexLayoutModule,
  StoreModule,
  StoreDevtoolsModule,
  TranslateModule,
  PrettyJsonModule,
  SimpleNotificationsModule
];

export const declarations = [GenerateIconComponent, ColorSearchedLettersDirective];

@NgModule({
  imports: modules,
  exports: [...modules, ...declarations],
  declarations
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Then I just import it in **every** sub-module.

You should take a look in official doc too :

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module

Comment: Thanx , And how to handle sub module routing with main routing ?

Comment: The correct link to shared modules is: https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules#sharing-modules